# JavaScript: Form onSubmit not calling function

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am currently learning JavaScript for my uni course and my function is not being called for some reason. I want to understand why this is not working.

**Brief Description**

There are two forms, one has a submit button, with the `onSubmit` field calling `document.write()` (This works), then calling my own function `submit()`. If I change `submit()` to `document.write()` then I receive two outputs, so there should be no reads why `submit` is not called?

The second form has a single textbox in it, I ideally want to make this disappear when the button is pressed, however I mainly want to understand why `submit` is not called.

```
<html charset="utf-8">
<head>
    <title>Game</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="get" name="form1" action="game.php" onSubmit="document.write('Hello');submit();">
        <input type="submit" value="submit" name="button" />
    </form>

    <form id="form2" name="form2">
        <input name="letter" type="text" />
    </form>
    <script>
        function submit() {
            alert("HELLO");
            document.getElementById('form2').visibility='hidden';
            document.write("Hello");
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

I have tried inserting the script in the header, above the function, below the function, but nothing seems to work.

Hope someone can help, thanks

Answer (score 5):

***submit*** is a reserved keyword. Change to any other name and it should work. Please find the JSFiddle of the same

https://jsfiddle.net/pc9rL2ey/

```
        function submita() {
            alert("HELLO");
            document.getElementById('form2').visibility='hidden';
            document.write("Hello");
        }


<form method="get" name="form1" action="game.php" onSubmit="submita();document.write('Hello');">
```

Comment: See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit) for (succinct?) documentation.